# Returning String using REST Endpoint

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

Before you minus this question, you should know I searched for solution and didn't find it.

I want to return String by rest endpoint:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/getMyString")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getId() {
    String s = "this is my string";
    (...)
    return Response.ok(s).build();
    }
```

But in view I receive char array (result in firebug):

```
Resource { 0="t", 1="h", 2="i", more...}
```

In front I use angular resource like:

```
blablaResources.factory('AngularApp', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(contextPath + '/.rest/v1/someService', {}, {
        (... other methods ...)
        getString : {
            method : 'GET',
            url : contextPath + '/.rest/v1/someService/getMyString'
        }
    });
} ]);
```

Is there any wrapper class for String or annotation to send it like:

```
Resource { value = "this is my string" }
```

or just normal

```
"this is my string"
```

Thanks for any constructive response :)

Comment: How does the response JSON look like on the wire (check with developer console or curl)? Just a string or something weird?

Comment: Did u try to create the result string as a JSON string directly? I mean...did u try to build String s="{this is my string}"?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation do you use ?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
```